# require class in protocol

Tags: objective-c, xcode, delegates, protocols

In a method in my protocol I require the class defined in the interface below, how do I solve this;

```
@protocol MyDelegate
-(void) somethingFinished:(MyObject*)object anyOtherData:(NSData*)data;
@end

@interface MyObject : NSObject
{
   id<MyDelegate> delegate;
}

// methods

@end
```

I get the error;

> Expected identifier before ':' token

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use forward declaration:

either:

```
@class MyObject;

@protocol MyDelegate
-(void) somethingFinished:(MyObject*)object anyOtherData:(NSData*)data;
@end

@interface MyObject : NSObject
{
   id<MyDelegate> delegate;
}
@end
```

or

```
@protocol MyDelegate;

@interface MyObject : NSObject
{
   id<MyDelegate> delegate;
}
@end

@protocol MyDelegate
-(void) somethingFinished:(MyObject*)object anyOtherData:(NSData*)data;
@end
```

Comment: I saw the 2nd option used more (and do that way myself), but 1st is also valid I think and there should not be any practical differences.

Comment: The first method is more classical C and is what most people would use. It's always nicer to see a class with the protocol above it as it gives you a quick easy way to see the 'contract' for the classes delegate / datasource etc.

Comment: All of the Apple headers do it protocol first then class interface.

Comment: hm, indeed. I wonder, why I'm using 2nd approach then... :) But they should not make any difference anyway